# How to show a Sales graph in TabHost using achartengine

Tags: android, android-tabhost, achartengine

Is there any way to display a chart in `TabHost` application in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/424752/1275274). You will get the resource for Graphs from here. And to display it on TabHost is i think you can do once you achieve the chart.

Hope this will help...